# Making up Salah while in a state of impurity

Tags: salat, ghusl, halal-haram

This is from 2017 when I started paying attention to Islam and Praying (before I had been a hypocrite)

Salam, one time I had been in a state of major impurity but I didn’t perform Ghusl as I thought maybe it wasn’t obligatory (and I feel as if I was probably too lazy and stuff), so I ended up Praying some Salah in this state

I can’t remember how many I performed while in this state and I haven’t Prayed them since then
must I pray them now?

Answer (score -2):

you made huge sin praying without ghusl.brother dont take these stuff lightly.
as for ur missed prayers,just repent to allah and be regular on ur salah from now on.